# Postman to fetch Office365 unread emails

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to fetch unread emails from inbox of my office365 account using postman.

With the help of Microsoft Graph API reference i am able to generate access token as in below format:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{AAA_UID}}/oauth2/token

{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3600",
    "ext_expires_in": "0",
    "expires_on": "1539180610",
    "not_before": "1539176710",
    "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
    "access_token": <ENCRYPTED_TOKEN>
}
```

However my requirement is to fetch unread mails from Inbox. In Graph Explorer I am able to get output with below url but while using in postman,getting `"Invalid authentication, access token is empty"` error.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages?$select=sender,subject
```

Can anyone please tell me how to append access token with the above code.

Or if you know any simple and better procedure to fetch unread emails from office365 account, please advice.

Answer (score 4):

The access token is sent in a request header to Microsoft Graph. In your GET request to `graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages`, include the `Authorization` request header and the value should be `Bearer YOUR_TOKEN`.

See the [Get access on behalf of a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user#4-use-the-access-token-to-call-microsoft-graph) documentation. Step 4 shows how to use the access token to call Microsoft Graph.

The reason it works in Graph Explorer is they include the token for you after you sign in. If you use Fiddler or F12 dev tools, you can see the token sent to Graph.

Answer (score 0):

The access_token is generally passed in the request headers. You could append access token with the above code:

You need add `Authorization : Bearer eyJ0eXAiO ... 0X2tnSQLEANnSPHY0gKcgw` to the request header.

Bearer is a keyword used frequently by sites implementing OAuth 2.

For more information, You could refer to this link:

[Get access on behalf of a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user#4-use-the-access-token-to-call-microsoft-graph)

Comment: I'm not sure why you added a separate answer that repeats what Dan Silver provided. If Dan's answer was correct (which it absolutely is), it should be marked as Accepted.